# .checked in not working for a button style input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the following script is suppose to return a variable from a function when it's clicked. however, it is returning me to 0.  is .checked the correct jquery to be using here?

js:

```
function getBedroomSizePrice()
{  
    var bedroomSizePrice=0;

    var theForm = document.forms["msform"];

    var selectedBoiler = theForm.elements["bedroom"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBoiler.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(selectedBoiler[i].checked)
        {           
            bedroomSizePrice = bedroom_prices[selectedBoiler[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return bedroomSizePrice;
}
```

html:

```
<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="button"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: I see "msform" in your js, but nowhere in your html.  Are you leaving out some html?

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes...

Comment: He is using bootstrap

Comment: Buttons !== checkboxes and delete your last question.

Comment: also, where is calculateTotal() defined?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change
type="radio" and not type="button"

```
<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">How Many Bedrooms Do You Have</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>
        <label >Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <br/>
        <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Bed1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Beds2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Beds3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Beds4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Beds5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5</label><br/>
                <label class='next action-button'><input type="radio"  name="bedroom" value="Beds6" onclick="calculateTotal()" />6</label><br/>

    </fieldset>
```